# How do I show months with the year in a hyperlink

Tags: php

- November 2011
- December 2011
- January 2012

I want to dynamically display dates in this pattern to make an archive for my article page. When a user clicks I want to get the parameters of the month and the year.

Comment: Do you need to do this between certain dates ? or based on some entries in a database ? ie how are you selecting the start and end date

Comment: yes i need on the bases of database in database my field is date-added and format to add article is 2011-12-02 05:11:58

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a database (mysql example given here) you can use `group by` :

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(date_field),YEAR(date_field) 
 FROM table_name 
 GROUP BY YEAR(date_field), MONTH(date_field)
```

This will output 2 columns, the first being the month and the second the year - then use PHP to create the dropdown / list or anchors.

If your field was called `date_added`, then this would be the query :

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(date_added),YEAR(date_added) 
 FROM table_name 
 GROUP BY YEAR(date_added), MONTH(date_added)
```

Working example : http://www.sqlize.com/36GGoUto7L

Comment: i have only one field date_added  in that date is stored no month and year field is dear

Comment: @user1124162 you only need one field - see my code - replace `date_field` with `date_added`

Comment: $quer=" SELECT date_added('".date('m')."'),date_added('".date('m')."')
       FROM articles
       GROUP BY date_added('".date('m')."'), date_added('".date('m')."')";

Comment: i make this query. as you mention give month name and year name. but i want take this dynamicall mate

Comment: @user1124162 what is date_added ? a column in the database ?

Comment: <?php
        $q=("SELECT MONTH(date_added),YEAR(date_added)
  FROM articles
  GROUP BY YEAR(date_added), MONTH(date_added)");  i got record but it is not store in my $row but when i print it it show reocrd 
  $rs = mysql_query($q) or die(" Error File : right_menu.inc.php ".mysql_error());
  while( $row = mysql_fetch_object($rs))
  {
  print_r($row);
  $row->MONTH(date_added);
  $row->YEAR(date_added);
  }

Comment: What do you see if you print_r your $row ? have you thought about using column aliases ?

Comment: i got now year and month. now problem is this i got months in numeric but i want show full month name in hyper link like december march etc sql return me  this value 12

Comment: @user1124162 use `MONTHNAME` instead of `MONTH` on `SELECT`

Comment: yes it return month name but in database month is save in numeric . i mean how can i convert this after getting reocrd

Comment: `$monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNum, 10));` where `$monthNum` is your number

Comment: bundle of thanx that is working now perfect .how can i vote your answer i am new user on stackovrflow

Comment: one question more @ManseUK  i send month and year in parameter in select querry i want retrive reocrd of that parmeters what will be sql query for select            <a href="<?=$_SESSION["site_url"]?>articles.html?month=<?=$row[0];?>&year=<?=$row[1];?>"><?php echo $monthName.$row[1]; ?> </a>              i got these two parmeters succefully on articles page on AND query operator how can apply for dat_added coloumn

Comment: mate i do it thanx a looooooooooooot. be happy